# Cannot set parameter for api request

Tags: python, api

I want to use this api: https://data.bka.gv.at/ris/api/v2.5/judikatur

This api allows the following query parameters as specified under: https://data.bka.gv.at/ris/api/v2.5/applications/judikatur

```
"Dokumenttyp":{"type":"JudikaturTypSucheinschraenkung","minOccurs":0,"documentation":"Art des Datensatzes: Text oder Rechtssatz"}
...
{"JudikaturTypSucheinschraenkung":{"elements":[{"name":"SucheInRechtssaetzen","type":"boolean","minOccurs":0,"maxOccurs":1,"default":"true"},{"name":"SucheInEntscheidungstexten","type":"boolean","minOccurs":0,"maxOccurs":1,"default":"true"}]}
```

I would like to query with "SucheInEntscheidungstexten" as False and "SucheInRechtssaetzen" as True. However, I cannot seem to specify these parameters.

I have tried the following so far:

```
import requests

parameters = {"EntscheidungsdatumVon": "2020-01-01", "SucheInEntscheidungstexten": "false"}
response = requests.get("https://data.bka.gv.at/ris/api/v2.5/judikatur", params=parameters)
```

How am I supposed to define these parameters?
In the end I would like to only get results with:

```
"Dokumenttyp": "Rechtssatz"
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing it correctly, I don't know what your actual or expected outputs are though. You aren't searching for anything specific, as you don't have "Suchworte." defined.
Also, don't forget to put SucheInRechtssaetzen in your parameters dictionary.
```parameters = {"EntscheidungsdatumVon": "2020-01-01", "SucheInEntscheidungstexten": "false", "SucheInRechtssaetzen": "true"}```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but even with the code snippet you posted, I also get results which should be filtered with "SucheInEntscheidungstexten": "false". Even when setting both to false, which would mean I should get no results, nothing changes.

Comment: I can only help so much, I don't speak I don't have the API documentation, and even if I did, I don't speak German...

Answer (score -1):

I think that the API do not take any parameters, but you can instead filter the data you want by converting the data to json then taking what you want from it

d = response.json()

Comment: It definitely does take parameters

Comment: True, other parameters like "EntscheidungsdatumVon" work just fine.